Missing \begin{document} error with macro
Ok, I created an MWE to clean this question.
The following code generates an error.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Include TikZ package for drawing
\usepackage{titling}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{questioncount}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 points)}\quad
}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1 cm,0.75cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\quiz}[2]{%
    \begin{document}
    \title{\noindent}
    \textbf{#1 #2} }
    \author{}
    \date{}
    \setlength{\droptitle}{-2.5cm} % Adjust the vertical space of the title
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{-2.5cm} 
    Name: \ans{6} NetID: \ans{4} Section \ans{1}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \hrule
}

\quiz{course}{title}
\q{30} instructions
\begin{itemize}
    \item What voltage is nominal (ideal) for 74LS parts? \ans{2}V
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

The error is:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.25     \maketitle
                   
? 


Please don't post code fragments. It's much easier for people to help you if you provide at least one compilable (even with error) minimal document. But your first idea shouldn't give you an error; it's correct.

Thanks, although not quite what I meant. This isn't very minimal. The idea would be to put one of your attempted ideas into a compilble document that people could play with. The error comes from your \quiz command which has an extra closing  brace too early in the command, right before \author. It has nothing to do with passing numeric arguments to commands. You also have \begin{document} inside the command, which it shouldn't be.

@AlanMunn oh I just noticed your comment:-)

@DavidCarlisle It's ok, I know you need the rep. :)

@AlanMunn deserve, not need, I'm sure you meant to say

Your example and error have no relation to the question in the title. You simply have a spurious } on line 21 so the definition of \quiz ends there and the \maketitle on line 25 is before \begin{document} so gives the error shown:
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.25     \maketitle
                   
? 

The presumably intended definition was:
\newcommand{\quiz}[2]{%
    \begin{document}
    \title{\noindent}
    \textbf{#1 #2}%%%%%%%%%%%% no } here
    \author{}
    \date{}
    \setlength{\droptitle}{-2.5cm} % Adjust the vertical space of the title
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{-2.5cm} 
    Name: \ans{6} NetID: \ans{4} Section \ans{1}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \hrule
}

